# HTML Template Language for Angularjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, slim-lang

I come from Rails, and have recently started doing some Angularjs. I am used to Sass, so I caught on to Less fairly quickly. I'd love to use something for HTML and possibly even JS.

1. Is there a HTML templating language like SLIM for Angular / Node / Sails?
2. Is there something like coffeescript for that stack? (is this a dumb question since it is a JS framework?)

Comment: angular has it's own templating ... how you generate the html and css is not anything to do with angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a HTML templating language like SLIM for Angular / Node / Sails?

The equivalent of SLIM would be a Node.js template engine, regardless of what you're using on the client (Angular or anything else). Some popular options are [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/).

> Is there something like CoffeeScript for that stack?

Again, [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) is framework agnostic, as it is just a language that compiles to JavaScript, so you could certainly use it in an Angular project or anywhere else that you'd normally write JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! Jade was what I was looking for.